# Can a table in one database declare OnetoMany declration for another table in different database

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, azure-sql-database

I was wondering if there is a way through which one Entity declare a OneToMany or access another table that is in different database through JPA.

Is it possible for JPA to access multiple databases and one entity referencing another entity of another database?

Thanks,
Anshu

Comment: As of my knowledge it is not possible!

Comment: If it is possible you'll need an XA capable transaction manager.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it in hibernate... Jpa will generate query for which database you have mapped in cfg file... You can't configure two db at once in single cfg file...

Comment: Well. My requirement, is that I need to have two seperate databases, as they are different applications. Its just that one of the app, contains data to store USER information. The other app does not have that data and not supposed to maintain it as well.